# Implement partial https for some webservices instead oh http

Tags: java, xml, http, https, jboss

I have this application and I have been asked to implement https, I have edited the XML file with the following lines:

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" 
           socket-binding="https" 
           enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
    <ssl name="kikou-ssl" key-alias="kikou" 
         password="kikou" 
         certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/kikou.keystore" 
         protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false"/>
</connector>
```

So far every thing is fine; I have HTTPs working fine, BUT, what I have to do is to use the HTTPS only for couple of wabservices! so I don't really know how to do it.

I thought about two solutions but I don't know really how to try them:

1. Edit the xml file with an attribut like : `javaclass="search"`.
2. Add something in the search class but here I don't know what to put, I have tried so far:

   ```
   if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString().contains("/user/account") && 
       servletRequest.getProtocol().contains("HTTP")) {
       throw new ResourceNotFoundException("The url should be HTTPS");
   }
   ```

But it didn't work.

Thank you for any comments or answers!

Comment: The context you have provided is minimal so I may be off-target but the answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281587/ssl-for-specific-pages-url-patterns-in-tomcat) may help you out.  The configuration involved would be in the web.xml file.

Comment: @dcbyers thank you for your comment, you mean that i should edit in my app the web.xml and not in the configuration file of my server standalone.xml ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify host and port when accessing a web service from JAX-WS-generated code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649019/how-do-i-specify-host-and-port-when-accessing-a-web-service-from-jax-ws-generate)